# Writng a DWORD registry key not working in vb script

Tags: vbscript, scripting, registry

im using the functions below to read and write to a 64bit registry from a 32bit scripting host.

It works fine reading & writing strings, but when I try and use a DWORD it fails

This works as a STRING

```
strResult = WriteRegStr (Write_REG_SZ, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\_TEST", "SubKey1", "1", 64)
```

But not as a DWORD, error is **VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't suport this property or method: 'oInParams.sValue'**

```
 strResult = WriteRegStr (Write_REG_DWORD, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\_TEST", "SubKey1", 1, 64)
```

Appreciate any help

```
'---------------------------------------------------
' Declared Constants 
'---------------------------------------------------

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10 
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const Read_REG_SZ = "GetStringValue"
Const Write_REG_SZ = "SetStringValue"
Const Read_REG_DWORD = "GetDWORDValue"
Const Write_REG_DWORD = "SetDWORDValue"
Const Success = 0
Const Failure = 1

'---------------------------------------------------
' Function Read Registry String
'---------------------------------------------------

Function ReadRegStr (Method, RootKey, Key, Value, RegType) 
    Dim oCtx, oLocator, oReg, oInParams, oOutParams 

    Set oCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet") 
    oCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", RegType 

    Set oLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator") 
    Set oReg = oLocator.ConnectServer("", "root\default", "", "", , , , oCtx).Get("StdRegProv") 

    Set oInParams = oReg.Methods_(Method).InParameters 
    oInParams.hDefKey = RootKey 
    oInParams.sSubKeyName = Key 
    oInParams.sValueName = Value 

    Set oOutParams = oReg.ExecMethod_(Method, oInParams, , oCtx) 

    Select Case Method
      Case "GetDWORDValue"  : ReadRegStr = oOutParams.uValue
      Case "GetStringValue" : ReadRegStr = oOutParams.sValue
    End Select


    'ReadRegStr = oOutParams.sValue 

    set oCtx = Nothing 
    set oLocator = Nothing 
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------
' Function Write Registry String
'---------------------------------------------------

Function WriteRegStr (Method, RootKey, Key, ValueName, Value, RegType) 

    Dim oCtx, oLocator, oReg, oInParams, oOutParams 

    Set oCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet") 
    oCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", RegType 

    Set oLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator") 
    Set oReg = oLocator.ConnectServer("", "root\default", "", "", , , , oCtx).Get("StdRegProv") 

    Set oInParams = oReg.Methods_(Method).InParameters 
    oInParams.hDefKey = RootKey 
    oInParams.sSubKeyName = Key 
    oInParams.sValueName = ValueName 
    oInParams.sValue = Value 

    Set oOutParams = oReg.ExecMethod_(Method, oInParams, , oCtx) 

    WriteRegStr = oOutParams.ReturnValue

    Set oCtx = Nothing 
    Set oLocator = Nothing 

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the property for DWORD values is `uValue`, not `sValue`.

You could handle that with a `Select Case` statement:

```
Select Case Method
  Case "SetDWORDValue"  : oInParams.uValue = Value
  Case "SetStringValue" : oInParams.sValue = Value
End Select
```

Note that you need the same for handling the data returned in `oOutParam` in the `ReadRegStr` function.

But frankly, in my opinion this attempt to build an abstraction for registry access is misguided, and I'd recommend to stick with the regular WMI methods. An abstraction would only be helpful if you wouldn't need to know the type of the value you're trying to read or write.

Comment: Thanks, I have the Write function now working, still issues with the Read Function, does this look ok? I've updated the function in my initial post.

Comment: @user2130499 You mean the modification to the `ReadRegStr` function? Yes, that should work AFAICS. To be on the safe side you could add a `Case Else` to the `Select Case` for handling situations where `Method` is not one of the defined strings.

Comment: Thanks, just checked it again and it seems to be working :) thanks for your help